# how to get a css that does not cause overflow of words beyond box

Tags: css

I've got a problem with long tag words (like Best Practices below).

I'd really appreciate if someone could go to the URL  http://www.siliconvalley-codecamp.com/ and make specific recommendation for the correct CSS change that would get the words like "Best-Practices" to clip when it goes over the edge rather than just flood over the edge into the screen.  Sadly, I'm not very good at css and general instructions will not do me much good since I'm not and don't have a css guy to help me.

It will be good for you karma and we will appreciate it very much.

[image: "Best Practices Overflow Problem"]

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it's too specific to your site, and unlikely to help any future visitors.  The best questions have a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code *directly* into the question. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Comment: I'd like to thank all those that spent the time to look at my example and suggest excellent answers.  I appreciate Katie expressing her opinion in a straight forward manner and not hiding behind a hidden button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I add `word-wrap:break-word` to the `.TagCloud` element, the words effectively wrap to the next line. You don't need a fixed width, just adding the `word wrap` property should effectively work.

Another alternative would be [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/). It is a jQuery plugin that condenses the font size to always fit in the allotted space.

Comment: thanks, worked perfect.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me on Chrome ! Do you still have the problem?

By the way you should give a fixed width to your div TagCloud and maybe use this

http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-white-space/

or this

```
div.TagCloud {
width: 250px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: When I add width: 250px and word-wrap: break-word it dos not seem to help  https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwEd6CU2mpA2dWI5R3FaSzFyTHM/edit?usp=sharing  135px seems to work better though

Comment: @PeterKellner it was just an example ! :) Put the width you need!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add `overflow: hidden` to the box? If you just want it to clip.